# How to print the value of intField in Maya python

Tags: python, maya

I want to print the value of intField given by user in maya using python.

**code**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def fun(number):
    print(number) 

cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
num = cmds.intField(changeCommand = 'fun()')
cmds.showWindow()
```

User will enter value in intField and i want to print that value

Answer (score 0):

You have to use lambda or partial :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

# Here is how i layout this kind of case :
# First the function that is not related to the ui 
def anyFuction(number):
    print(number) 

# i create a parser who will query value by default but some ui elements may use other arguments
# I put kwargs for example if you want to query another flag (for some simple ui, i even put as argument the cmds.intField)
# note that i had if your function as some other things to pass throught
# if you have multiple fields to query you can bind the function into another function example below the code
def queryIntfield(function='', uiNameElem, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        v = cmds.intField(uiNameElem, q=True, **kwargs)
    else:
        v = cmds.intField(uiNameElem, q=True, v=1)

    if len(args) > 1:    
        function(v, *args)
    elif function = '':
        return v
    else:
        function(v)


cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
# create the field to get his name : num
num = cmds.intField(changeCommand = '')# do not put a function in comma
# edit the command placeholder 
cmds.intField(num, e=1, changeCommand = partial(ui_queryIntfield, anyFuction, num))
cmds.showWindow()
```

----- Example 2

```
'''

# Example 2 

# Here is how i layout this kind of case :
# First
def anyFuction(number):
    print(number) 
# Second
def queryIntfield(uiNameElem, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        v = cmds.intField(uiNameElem, q=True, **kwargs)
    else:
        v = cmds.intField(uiNameElem, q=True, v=1)
    return v
# Third, if it is a complex function, i duplicate the name anyFunction and add ui_ to know im binding this function with ui
def ui_anyFunction(uiNameElem, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do some stuff
    value = queryIntfield(uiNameElem)
    # and other stuff
    # .....
    # ..............
    anyFuction(value)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda or partial, or you can simply define your callback function in a scope where the UI element already exists so it knows the name of the UI:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def fun(number):
    print(number) 

cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
num = cmds.intField()
def num_callback():
    print cmds.intField(num, q=True, value=True)
cmds.intField(num, e=True, changeCommand = num_callback)
cmds.showWindow()
```

In general you want to avoid using the string form of callback assignment: it's a common source of problems where maya cannot find the function if you're not in the listener.  More detail [here](https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet)